# Kendo Angular Charts side by side

Tags: angular, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I'm trying to put kendo angular charts side by side, but they keep stacking. I'm using bootstrap col-md-6 and have tried other styles, but the kendo-chart elements aren't respecting anything and they keep taking up the whole row and stacking. Removing style="display:inline-block;" still doesn't work. Here is what I've got in the html:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;">
            <kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
                    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
                    <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
                    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
                    <kendo-chart-series>
                        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                            type="line" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                        </kendo-chart-series-item>
                    </kendo-chart-series>
                </kendo-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="display:inline-block;">
            <kendo-chart>
                    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
                        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Miles' }"
                                                     [min]="0" [max]="100">
                        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
                    </kendo-chart-value-axis>
                    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
                        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="categories2">
                        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
                    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
                    <kendo-chart-series>
                      <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="series2" type="line">
                      </kendo-chart-series-item>
                    </kendo-chart-series>
                  </kendo-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "col-md-6" elements need to be within an element with class="row" for the bootstrap layout to work:

[BOOTSTRAP GRID SYSTEM](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
                    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
                    <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
                    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
                    <kendo-chart-series>
                        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                            type="line" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                        </kendo-chart-series-item>
                    </kendo-chart-series>
                </kendo-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
           <kendo-chart [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }">
                    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
                    <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
                    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
                    <kendo-chart-series>
                        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                            type="line" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                        </kendo-chart-series-item>
                    </kendo-chart-series>
                </kendo-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/8I3l8pLWRvOTFiKQscuk?p=preview)